# How do I keep count of all the elements inside hashes which are inside an array?

Tags: ruby

Basically, I have an array which contains 3 hashes. I want to count and return each key and value  inside the hashes, which include any duplicates. The code is below, I have done the first draft of the code as you can see for yourself below.

```
my_array = [{:name => "blake"}, {:name => "blake"}, {:name => "ashley"}]
 #Count the number of times each element appears inside the hash
 #so the output should have the number of times the :names, "blake" and "ashley" element appears
 #EXPECTED OUTPUT: :name = 3, "blake" = 2, "ashley" = 1

def getOccurances(array)
  array.group_by{|v| v[:name]}.map{|k,v| {name: k, count: v.length}}
end 

getOccurances(my_array)
#ACTUAL OUTPUT: {:name => "blake", :count => 2}, {:name => "ashley", :count => 1}
```

Comment: What is your question? Does your code work? What is the expect, what the actual output?

Comment: my question is that how do I count each element inside the hash stated on the code. So the output should be :name = 3, "blake" = 2, "ashley" = 1. Thats what I want from the code. The actual output from my code is commented out above as you can see.

Comment: Ok, so you want to count the keys as values too. I’d recommend you update your question to clarify that. If your bonus comment is supposed to explain that, that’s way too unclear.

Comment: `my_array.group_by { |v| v[:name] }.map { |k, v| [k, v.length] }`

Answer (score 1):

You can map each Hash to an Array of [key, val] pairs, then flatten and each occurrence:

```
[{:name => "blake"}, {:name => "blake"}, {:name => "ashley"}].
    map(&:to_a).flatten.
    reduce(Hash.new { 0 }) {|o, v| o[v] += 1; o }
```

The argument to `reduce` is a Hash initialized with a block, so the default value of uninitialized keys is 0; we simply iterate through the flattened entries and accumulate a count of values.

Answer (score 0):

```
my_array.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |g,h| h[g[:name]] += 1 }.
         map { |k,v| { name: k, count: v } }
  #=> [{:name=>"blake", :count=>2}, {:name=>"ashley", :count=>1}]
```

Note:

```
my_array.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |g,h| h[g[:name]] += 1 }
  #=> {"blake"=>2, "ashley"=>1}
```